# Problem with installation of LaTeXDraw!

Tags: command-line, permissions, latex

I was using LaTexDraw 2, which I had got it form Ubuntu Software Center. As the functions were limited and I couldn't use math to label out, I searched and found this new 3.1 version.

After downloading it. I followed the manual and ran the installer using the script provided.It showed that it installed peacefully in `/opt`.

Launching directly from terminal worked, using superuser.

Problems.

1. Not able to launch the app as a normal user.
   It shows this error.

   ```
   $ latexdraw 
   $ Error: Unable to access jarfile /root/Desktop/latexdraw/LaTeXDraw.jar
   ```
2. The `.jar` file has is in the root folder, for some reason!!?? It should have been in the `/opt` folder. I have tried changing the ownership, but in no use.
3. Then there is the problem with the .desktop file. It doesn't do anything. No shortcuts or launches. Do I need to modify this file? And where do I need to put it?

So any help how to make this app run in normal mode (without superuser) and launching it directly with the command latexdraw from the terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Download the version 3.3.1 from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/latexdraw/files/latest/download?source=typ_redirect).
2. Extract the archive in your download folder with

   ```
   unzip LaTeXDraw-3.3.1-bin.zip
   ```
3. Start the installer **without** `sudo`

   ```
   LaTeXDraw-3.3.1/install_debian_ubuntu
   ```
4. Use `/opt` as target folder
5. Start <kbd>Latexdraw</kbd> via the Dash

Comment: Thanks.
It did install but export as .eps is not working as well as the LaTeX mode.